# What is the last heavy atom of an amino acid?

Tags: bioinformatics, amino-acids

I'm a electrical engineer and I'm learning about bioinformatics. I was reading this paper that uses the last heavy atom to search for active sites of a protein but what would be a heavy atom? Is it all atoms but hydrogen? Atoms heavier than carbon? And how do I know which is the last heavy atom?

The article: http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2014/11/08/bioinformatics.btu746.full.pdf+html

It talks about the last heavy atom under Materials and Methods 2.1.1 Individual Representation and Population Initialization

Comment: Your description is not quite clear. Can you please give the complete reference for the article you're reading, and also the precise quote?

Comment: http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2014/11/08/bioinformatics.btu746.full.pdf+html

Comment: It's under materials and methods on 2.1.1 Individual representation and population initialization

Comment: I haven't heard of this concept before, but it looks like the LHA is a reference atom at the "end" of the amino acid side chain. The precise definition appears to be empirical / heuristic, see http://www.cbi.cnptia.embrapa.br/SMS/STINGm/help/lha.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by Roland, this term is not common and is first used by the authors of the mentioned paper (also the package mentioned by Roland in comments - STING).

From this [link](http://www.cbi.cnptia.embrapa.br/SMS/STINGm/help/lha.html) you can find the definition of the Last Heavy Atom which is possibly the most distal non-hydrogen (N, C, O, S) atom in the amino-acid side chain.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Ala\ :\ C_\beta & Asp\ :\ O_{\delta^2}  &Trp\ :\ C_{\eta^2}  &Asn\ :\ N_{\delta^2} \\
\hline
Lys\ :\ N_\zeta & Glu\ :\ O_{\epsilon^2}  & Ser\ :\ O_\gamma  & Gln\ :\ N_{\epsilon^2} \\
\hline
Cys\ :\ S_\gamma  & His\ :\ N_{\epsilon^2}  & Tyr\ :\ O_\eta  & Val\ :\ C_{\gamma^2} \\
\hline
Gly\ :\ C_\alpha  & Leu\ :\ C_{\delta^2}  & Met\ :\ C_\epsilon  & Ile\ :\ C_{\delta^1} \\
\hline
Arg\ :\ N_{\eta^2} & Phe\ :\ C_\zeta  & Pro\ :\ C_\delta  & Thr\ :\ C_{\gamma^2} \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

They have mentioned in the same link that:

> If in any of the PDB files (to be analyzed by the BLUE STAR STING components) that specific atom (LHA) is missing in the record, then our algorithms will search for the next closer atom in the side chain that would be considered as the LHA.

---

## The exact location of some of the abovementioned atoms.

Some of the locations might be confusing. So I am just indicating what these are, for a few the amino acids (especially for the branched and cyclic side chains). 
<sub>[*Images reproduced from [here](http://www.biology.arizona.edu/biochemistry/problem_sets/aa/aa.html)*.]</sub>

### Arginine

[image]

The terminal nitrogens $\eta^1$ and $\eta^2$ are symmetric and the atom that is actually (stereochemically) the most distal is considered the LHA, as inferred from the protein structure. The second choice, obviously is the $\eta^1$-Nitrogen.

### Aspartic acid

[image]

The two terminal oxygens ($\delta^1$ and $\delta^2$) in the ionized form are equivalent (also otherwise because of resonance). The actual distal atom would be labelled as $\delta^2$

*you can extrapolate the same for Glutamic acid*

### Histidine

[image]

$\epsilon^2$ refers to the pyrollic nitogen. .

### Leucine

[image]

The last carbons ($\delta^1$ and $\delta^2$) are equivalent and the choice is based on the actual distance. *Extrapolate for valine*

### Phenylalanine

[image]

$\zeta$ refers to the carbon in the *para*-position of the benzene ring. For tyrosine the LHA is the oxygen of the *para*-OH in the benzene ring.

### Tryptophan

[image]

### Proline

[image]

For **Aspargine** and **Glutamine** the LHA is the amide nitrogen of the side chain.

Comment: From a search of Web of Science, it appears that LHA is a term that has been coined by informaticians and is not something that is used in Biochemistry or Organic Chemistry. There are only three articles that are under the topic "Last Heavy Atom," and all three are Informatics Journals. The abstract of this article gives a decent "definition" of the term. http://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/1758-2946-1-13

Comment: @AMR Yes it is not a standard term. There are quite some articles that use this term but I guess they are the ones using the abovementioned protein structural biochemistry package.

Comment: Seems a bit weird for the cyclic sidechains (except proline), given that they can rotate around the Calpha-Cbeta bond...